# images not loading when uploaded to godaddy

Tags: html, css, image, file-upload

there seems to be a problem with one of my folders!

I have my website working on my local files here, but when i uploaded them to the host website, godaddy.com, it doesn't work... the problem seems to be on the IMAGES folder, but i cant find anything wrong with the files/folder! i have deleted and uploaded twice just to make sure it's no corrupted or anything...
any ideas?

```
background-image: url('images/Background_main.jpg');
```

[www.tasteofbrazilkc.com](http://www.tasteofbrazilkc.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So two problems.

**First**, the web server is *case sensitive*.  Your CSS seems to have been designed on a web server or operating system that was not.  So, you'll need to change:

```
background-image: url('images/Background_main.jpg');
```

Needs to be:

```
background-image: url('Images/Background_main.jpg');
```

Or, rename `Images` to `images` on the web server.

**Second.**  Your CSS file is relative to `/style`.  Thus `images/` would refer to `/style/images/`.  It might be a good idea to put a `/` at the beginning so you can qualify the entire folder:

```
background-image: url('/Images/Background_main.jpg');
```

Though you could also do:

```
background-image: url('../Images/Background_main.jpg');
```

[This](http://www.tasteofbrazilkc.com/Images/Background_main.jpg) seems to be the image you're after.

Comment: thank you so much!
it works now!
didn't now some programs were case sensitive and some were not!

Thank you!

Comment: Yea, generally Unix based web servers are case-sensitive and Windows based servers are not.